# Add Dropdown Menu to CRM 2011 ribbon

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I 'm new to crm 2011. I've found documentation on how to add a new button to the ribbon. And how to group the buttons. But i need a dropdown menu button in the ribbon. How can i do this? I didn't found any information about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should get you started.  If all you need is a static menu you can put the  tag inside the Flyout Control and build the menu from there.

```
<FlyoutAnchor Id="Sample.account.form.FlyoutAnchor.Static"
              Sequence="10"
              Command="Mscrm.Enabled"
              Image16by16="/_imgs/placeholders/ribbon_placeholder_16.png"
              Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/newrecord32.png"
              LabelText="Sample Flyout"
              Alt="Sample Flyout"            
              TemplateAlias="isv">
  <Menu Id="Sample.account.form.Menu">
    <MenuSection Id="Sample.account.form.MenuSection" 
                 Title="Menu Section Title" 
                 Sequence="15">
      <Controls Id="Sample.account.form.MenuSection.Controls">
        <Button Id="Sample.account.form.Controls.Button.FirstButton"
                Command="Sample.ButtonCommand.Command"
                LabelText="First Button"
                ToolTipTitle="First Button"
                ToolTipDescription="The first button"
                TemplateAlias="isv"
                Sequence="20"/>
      </Controls>
    </MenuSection>
  </Menu>
</FlyoutAnchor>
```

If you want to generate the menu Dynamically you can use this flyout control instead.  Note the Populate attributes that were added.
Then you have to build the menu through javascript.

```
<FlyoutAnchor Id="Sample.account.form.FlyoutAnchor.Dynamic"
              Sequence="10"
              Command="Mscrm.Enabled"
              Image16by16="/_imgs/placeholders/ribbon_placeholder_16.png"
              Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/newrecord32.png"
              LabelText="Sample Flyout"
              Alt="Sample Flyout"
              PopulateDynamically="true"
              PopulateQueryCommand="Sample.PopulateDynamicMenu"
              TemplateAlias="isv" />
```

I created two commands that access the javascript functions.  DynamicMenu builds the menu and the Search is used to determine which button control was pressed.  Note both of these pass the CommandProperties parameter this is important for the javascript.

```
<CommandDefinition Id="Sample.PopulateDynamicMenu">
      <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.Enabled" />
      </EnableRules>
      <DisplayRules />
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="DynamicMenu"
                            Library="$webresource:a_JavaScript_File">
          <CrmParameter Value="CommandProperties" />
        </JavaScriptFunction>
      </Actions>
</CommandDefinition>
<CommandDefinition Id="Sample.SearchCommand">
      <EnableRules />
      <DisplayRules />
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="Search" 
                            Library="$webresource:a_JavaScript_File">
          <CrmParameter Value="CommandProperties" />
        </JavaScriptFunction>
      </Actions>
</CommandDefinition>
```

Here are the javascript functions:

```
function DynamicMenu(CommandProperties) {
    ///<summary>Dynamically generate menu items based on context</summary>
    /// <param name="CommandProperties">
    ///    Command properties crm parameter sent from the ribbon.  object used to inject the Menu XML
    /// </param>

    var menuXml = '<Menu Id="Sample.DynamicMenu">' +
                    '<MenuSection Id="Sample.Dynamic.MenuSection" Sequence="10">' +
                        '<Controls Id="Sample.Dynamic.Controls">' +
                            '<Button Id="Sample.account.form.Controls.Button.FirstButton"' +
                                    ' Command="Sample.SearchCommand"' +
                                    ' LabelText="First Button"' +
                                    ' ToolTipTitle="First Button"' +
                                    ' ToolTipDescription="The first button"' +
                                    ' TemplateAlias="isv"' +
                                    ' Sequence="20" />' +                                  
                        '</Controls>' +
                    '</MenuSection>' +
                '</Menu>';


    CommandProperties.PopulationXML = menuXml;
}

function Search(CommandProperties) {
    ///<summary>Determines which control was pressed</summary>
    /// <param name="CommandProperties">
    ///    Command properties crm parameter sent from the ribbon.  object used to read which dynamically generated
    ///    button is selected.
    /// </param>

    var controlId = CommandProperties.SourceControlId;
    switch (controlId) {
        case 'Sample.account.form.Controls.Button.FirstButton':
            alert(controlId + ' was pressed!');
            break;        
        default:
            alert('unknown');
    }
}
```

Comment: When i call the DynamicMenu function, what should i pass as Parameter? (The commandproperties)

Comment: Crm passes the variables you need.  That is what this XML line is for  <CrmParameter Value="CommandProperties" />.  In the functions I just put the same name for consistency, you do not have to.  Here is a list of the possible parameters you can tell CRM to send: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309332.aspx

Comment: any reason why this is not working for me? i copy paste'd your code for first & second exmaple both do not work for crm 2011 on premise for me. I get a XML Error on opening the From. I added a correct Location of a other button, which I deleled

Comment: It is hard to troubleshoot without knowing what the error is.  An XML Error lends me to believe you have a schema validation error in the XML generated by the JavaScript function (if you had an error in the RibbonDiffXML the solution would not import). Make sure you did not accidentally delete a `"` somewhere. Next I would make sure all of the IDs and Sequence numbers are correct.  Duplicates will cause problems.