# Dynamics CRM 2011: CommandProperties CrmParameter not set correctly when passed to FlyoutAnchor JavaScript function

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon, ribbon-control, flyout

I'm trying to create three dynamically filled FlyoutAnchor Ribbon buttons, based on the following SO answer: [Add Dropdown Menu to CRM 2011 ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819080/add-dropdown-menu-to-crm-2011-ribbon?answertab=active#tab-top)

All three FlyoutAnchor buttons use the same *PopulateQueryCommand*. The JavaScript function which is linked to the command (see code block below) gets the *CommandProperties* CrmParameter passed as the first argument to be able identify the flyout button which was clicked (and should be filled with dynamically added dropdown menu items).

```js
function DynamicMenu(CommandProperties) {
    /// <summary>Dynamically generate menu items based on context</summary>
    /// <param name="CommandProperties">
    ///    Command properties crm parameter sent from the ribbon.  object used to inject the Menu XML
    /// </param>

    debugger;

    var menuXml = '<Menu Id=\"Sample.DynamicMenu\">' +
                       // ... Other menu XML stuff goes here
                  '</Menu>';

    CommandProperties.PopulationXML = menuXml;  // error here...PopulationXML is undefined... :-(

    // ...
}
```

The function gets nicely called and the 'CommandProperties' argument is passed (it isn't `null` and not `undefined`), but when I try to set the PopulationXML I get an error, because this property is `undefined`. The other three expected properties listed below are also `undefined`:

- **SourceControlId**: The Id value of the Ribbon control that initiated the event.
- **CommandValueId**: A string that is sent with the command event when a button is clicked.
- **MenuItemId**: A reference from a control to the Id of a menu item.

When I pass in a second different CrmParameter, for example *PrimaryEntityTypeName*, this argument is correctly filled / set.

What could be the cause of the messed-up `CommandProperties` argument?

**Update 21-2-2012**: To be complete, I also tried the single button approach, such as described in [Add Dropdown Menu to CRM 2011 ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819080/add-dropdown-menu-to-crm-2011-ribbon?answertab=active#tab-top), but that gave me the same result (no usable Commandproperties object). My CRM server is running Rollup 6, maybe that has something to do with it? Is there a different way of getting this kind of flyout ribbon menu's? Maybe something in pure JavaScript? It should also work in the Outlook CRM Client...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, the resolution is instead of using 
'<Menu Id=\"Sample.DynamicMenu\">', use '<Menu Id="Sample.DynamicMenu">' 
the difference is of not using escape character for "

Comment: Removing the escape characters worked for creating the sub menu item, which is really great!!, but I still can't get the properties like 'CommandProperties.SourceControlId'. So I can't differentiate between the different buttons clicked. As a workaround I would have to add different CommandDefinitions for each FlyoutAnchor button. Do you also know how to get these properties?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: I know it's a late answer, and probably figured it already out. You can set Id's for the buttons and then check the Id's